# How to create dependency in MS Excel 2010?

Tags: excel

I'm new to Excel and need help in creating a Excel tracker. Here is the requirement:

I have 4 columns - Creation date, team name, Priority and SLA. 
Each Team and priority pair has different SLAs. Depending on the team and priority value we select, SLA should be calculated automatically.

For example, If team-A and priority-1 has a SLA of 5 days, SLA should automatically get populated that is add 5 business days to creation date and give the date when the SLA ends.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Vijeth

Comment: If there is an algorithm behind your question, you can write it as a worksheet function... or as an UDF. .. while I don't get what you desire in specific. .

Comment: Having the "current date" which does not change later needs at least iteration...while it may be easier to use an UDF or input the date manually...

Comment: Save a table with all the values for every combination of team and priority.
Use this table and v-look-up the SLA days from this source table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use "if function" and nest it with the AND function to achieve this, here is the syntax

```
IF(condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )
```

for example:

```
IF(AND(Priority=1, team=A),SLA=date+5, IF(AND(Priority = 2, team=B)SLA=date+6, etc))
```

On this site are some more examples for understanding
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php